# MVC4 tutorial - Eager loading of a property of a foreign key object, that has itself been eager loaded

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working with MVC4 and EF5, and I have been working through the Contoso University tutorial on this page:
http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-basic-crud-functionality-with-the-entity-framework-in-asp-net-mvc-application

Relevant parts of the The Entity Framework model classes:

```
public class Student
{
    public int StudentID { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Enrollment> Enrollments { get; set; }
}

public enum Grade { A,B,C,D,F}
public class Enrollment
{
    public int EnrollmentID { get; set; }
    public int CourseID { get; set; }
    public int StudentID { get; set; }
    public Grade? Grade { get; set; }
    public Course Course { get; set; }
    public Student Student { get; set; }
}

public class Course
{
    public int CourseID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Enrollment> Enrollments { get; set; }
}
```

In the Controller:

```
public ActionResult Details(int id = 0) {
    Student student = db.Students.Find(id);
    return View(student);
}
```

The relevant bit of the view:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Enrollments) {
    <tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Course.Title) //this does not display as Course is null
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Grade)
    </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Contrary to what the tutorial says, for me the view does not display the Course Title, it only shows the Grade.

```
Course Title    Grade
                A
                C
                B
```

Debugging shows that the Course property (representing the foreign key to Course) is null.
In other words, for each Student, the Enrollments collection is loaded, but those enrollments have not loaded their Course property.
I cannot work out how to use Eager Loading to load the Course property of each Enrollment.
How do I get the Course Title to display in the view?

I have found that a hard coded "Include" string works (in the Controller):

```
Student student = db.Students.Where(x => x.StudentID == id).Include("Enrollments.Course").Single();
```

But I cannot work out how to do it with a lambda function or any other function.

I have tried the following with no success:

```
Student student = db.Students.Where(x => x.StudentID == id).Include(y => y.Enrollments.Course).Single();
Student student = db.Students.Where(x => x.StudentID == id).Include(y => y.Enrollments).Include(z => z.Enrollments.Course).Single();
```

Comment: is course id populated?

Comment: yes. in the Enrollments collection of the student object, all properties are populated apart from Course. So CourseID,EnrollmentID,Grade,Student, and StudentID are all not null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dont forget this in your c# file:

```
using System.Data.Entity;
```

EDIT:

Or just mark your Course property as virtual for lazy loading

```
public class Enrollment
{

        public virtual Course Course { get; set; }
        public virtual Student Student { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, unfortunately it doesn't work, as "y => Enrollments.Course" has the compiler error: "cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type". So in other words it is the same as when I did it using 'z'.

Comment: yes, that is included at the top. No red squiggly lines in visual studio 2012. in your suggestion it is only "(y => Enrollments.Course)" that is underlined

Comment: Oops. Sorry that was a syntax error. change it to `y =>  y.Enrollments.Course`

Comment: I should have spotted that too, but it still gives the same compiler error. I think it is because Enrollments is a collection, and so that has no Course property.

Comment: Right. To solve your problem, just add the virtual keyword to the model property of your Enrollment model just like the tutorial instructed. Check my edit.

Comment: you've got it, thanks very much for your efforts. I see now the significance of the virtual keyword.

Comment: I have edited the answer to remove the part that does not compile